# To run Phonon on Windows XP sp2

Tags: windows, qt

can anyone tell me from where i can get a fully functional phonon that runs on windows, if compilation needed , then from where i can download directly the compiled output. Or tell me which other multimedia toolkit can be used with QT and how ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Phonon's dlls that you'll find in the "bin" folder of Qt's installs !

You could for example try and compile this example :

http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/phonon-qmusicplayer.html

With the latest Qt version that you'll find here : http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

I hope I got your question right and it helps a bit !

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to make sure your using the Visual Studio compiler, the mingw compiler cannot link to the windows multimedia framework.

Comment: MinGW releases based on GCC 4.4 or above should be able to build the Phonon DirectShow backend - see this posting for more details: http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/07/15/phonon-and-mingw-a-story-about-true-windows-love/